# Email-to-Case auto-response email not received but Salesforce shows as delivered

Tags: email2case, case-auto-response

I just set up Email-to-Case for an org that was using Email Agent(*yes, hard to believe*).

When I send email to `staging-support@mycompany.com`, Salesforce Case AutoResponse rules are configured to execute and send a canned email template back to the sender.

Yet ...

- Debug log shows Case Auto Response rule executing and generating an email response
- Salesforce shows email as delivered (R/D in email log)
- Mail does not appear in sender's inbox!
- Mail is not in spam or trash !

And further yet ...

- If I send via the SFDC Case UX the exact same template as used in the Case AutoResponse rules ...
- The mail is received by the recipient

What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The org uses Email Relay and I needed to get IT support from the Mail Server team

They observed the following in the mail server's logs:

```
Oct 12 18:04:07 edge04e postfix/smtp[3729]: 6E6AF534CC3: 
to=<footest@gmail.com>, 
relay=mail.mycompany.com[129.xxx.xxx.xxx]:25, 
delay=0.13, delays=0.02/0/0.04/0.07, dsn=5.7.1, 
status=bounced (host mail.mycompany.com[129.xxx.xxx.xxx] 
said: 554 5.7.1 [VO-1] Message blocked due to spam content in the message. (in reply to end of DATA command))
```

Turns out the spam filter was sensitive to how SFDC Case Autoresponse replies are constructed but not sensitive to the same email template used in a Send Email command from the UX